# Room Вложенный List

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Нужно записать в базу данные с такой структурой: List внутри каждого объекта еще один List кастомного типа

```
List<Big>



   class Big{
      String value1;
      String value2;
    ....
      List<Small> list;
    }

    class Small{
      String value1;
      String value2;
    ....

    }
```

Собственно, как поместить внутренний  List в базу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я понял это отношения "один ко многим", где у одного `Big` может быть много `Small` (я не знаю что вы проектируете но названия "очень" информативны). 
Можете использовать следующую схему:

```
   @Entity
   class Big{
      @PrimaryKey int id;
      String value1;
      String value2;
    ....
    }

    @Entity(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
             entity = Big.class,
             parentCollumns = "id",
             childColumns = "bigId"))
    class Small{
      @PrimaryKey int id;
      int bigId; // здесь хранится id big сущности
      String value1;
      String value2;
    ....
    }
```

Данное построение обеспечит ограничение по внешнему ключу между обьектами. Вы можете получить все обекты `Small` в `DAO` таким образом:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM WHERE bigId IS :bigId")
List<Small> getSmall(String bigId);
```

Comment: Вроде как до этого `getSmall(String bigId);` bigid был типом `int`. Соответственно: `@Query("SELECT * FROM WHERE bigId = :bigId")`